# Why i got 'Graph Execution Error?' when predict deep learning model

Tags: python, tensorflow

First of all i already load my model to predict inference set that i already prepared, but i got error when to try predict and show the result.

so here my code

```
def load_img(filename):
  img = read_file(filename) # Load Data
  img = decode_image(img, channels=3) # convert to RGB
  img = resize(img, size=[img_height, img_height])
  img = np.array(img)[:,:,1] # Resize image
  img = img/255. # Rescale Images
  return img

inf1 = load_img(r'ML2\COVID-19\inf_set\covid\covid - 1.jpeg')
inf2 = load_img(r'ML2\COVID-19\inf_set\covid\covid - 2.jpeg')
inf3 = load_img(r'ML2\COVID-19\inf_set\normal\Normal - 1.jpeg')
inf4 = load_img(r'ML2\COVID-19\inf_set\normal\Normal - 2.jpeg')
inf5 = load_img(r'ML2\COVID-19\inf_set\pneumonia\Pneumonia - 1.jpeg')
inf6 = load_img(r'ML2\COVID-19\inf_set\pneumonia\Pneumonia - 2.jpeg')


plt.figure(figsize=(35, 5))
plt.suptitle('Prediction Results', fontsize=15)
counter = 1
for i in [inf1,inf2, inf3, inf4, inf5,inf6]:
    plt.subplot(1,6,counter)
    res = int(tf.round(model.predict(x=expand_dims(i, axis=0))))
    plt.imshow(i)
    plt.title(f"Prediction: {label_data[res]}")
    plt.axis('off')
    counter += 1
plt.show()
```

And here the error notification
[image]

So, i need help to solve this proble, thank you before

Comment: Why do you write this line : `img = np.array(img)[:,:,1] # Resize image`

Answer (score 0):

You are squashing the image size in this line

```
img = np.array(img)[:,:,1]
```

This is why your image becomes size `(220,220)` instead of `(220,220,1)`, which when you do `expand_dims` will be of proper input shape `(1,220,220,1)`

You could change the `load_img` function, or you could solve this by doing

```
res = int(tf.round(model.predict(x=expand_dims(i, axis=[0,3]))))
```

Comment: Still got error when i tried change axis on expand_dims sir

Comment: You're getting the same error?

Comment: It's okay , already solved,
thank you sir